# why doesn't FDA drug list include all meds?

Tags: usa, openfda, drugs

The FDA has a drug list that I would have thought would have had all FDA approved drugs. The list can be downloaded here:

https://www.fda.gov/drugs/informationondrugs/ucm079750.htm

You can search it online here:

https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm

The problem is...  not all drugs appear in it. A few examples:

- [Monovisc](https://www.drugs.com/history/monovisc.html)
- [Orthovisc](https://www.drugs.com/history/orthovisc.html)

According to drugs.com these drugs are FDA approved so why aren't they in the FDA drug list? I note that the generic for each of these is the same...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FDA CDER database, which you linked to, covers small molecule drugs.

Monovisc is a medical device, so you'll need to search the medical device database: https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRL/rl.cfm

Comment: Is there a downloadable database that'd have this info?

Comment: https://www.fda.gov/MedicalDevices/DeviceRegulationandGuidance/HowtoMarketYourDevice/RegistrationandListing/ucm134495.htm